# ¿Cómo puedo mostar por eje: 63000000 minutos en horas:minutos:segundos con PHP - codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$minutos = 63000000;
echo hh:mm:ss
```

Según la cantidad de minutos deseo mostrar este dato en Horas:minutos:segundos, yo lo realicé así:

```
if ($minutosCursos != 0) {
  $segundosCurso = $minutosCursos * 60;
  $horas = floor($segundosCurso / 3600);
  $minutos = floor(($segundosCurso - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
  $segundos = $segundosCurso - ($horas * 3600) - ($minutos * 60);
  $tiempoTotalUsuarioCursos = $horas . ':' . $minutos . ':'  . $segundos;
} else {
  $tiempoTotalUsuarioCursos = 0;
}
```

Comment: Ese dato en minutos representa `43750` días. ¿Puedes dar más precisión sobre lo que quieres hacer realmente? ¿Quierés dividir `43750` días en horas, minutos y segundos?

Comment: @A.Cedano quiero dividir los minutos en horas, minutos y segundos. Quiero saber si hay una forma mucho más óptima a la que realicé. Abajo voy agregar una mejora a la solución que plantee arriba pero me causa curiodad encontrar algo mucho mejor.

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Qué es `63000000`? Son `63000000`  minutos?

Comment: @A.Cedano si son minutos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fechas yo prefiero trabajar con la clase `DateTime()`. Trabajas sobre seguro y puedes usar sus métodos para obtener los datos que requieras.

Con esta función podrías obtener lo que necesitas. Dado que lo quieres en `hh:mm:ss` la función determina los días que pueda haber y los multiplica por 24 para pasarlos a horas. He puesto un comentario en cada parte para que sepas lo que se va haciendo.

### Función

```
function minutesToTime($mins) {
    #Controlamos que el parámetro sea válido
    if (!$mins || $mins < 0) return false;
    #Convertimos a segundos
    $seconds=$mins*60;
    #Creamos fecha Epoch
    $mEpoch = new DateTime('@0');
    #Creamos fecha basada en $seconds
    $mDate = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    #Calculamos intervalo
    $i=$mEpoch->diff($mDate);   
    #Verificamos si tiene días y los multiplicamos por 24
    #y al mismo tiempo se los sumamos a las horas
    #Si no tiene días, obtenemos las horas
    $h= ($i->format('%a') >= 1) ? $i->format('%a')*24  +  $i->format('%H'): $i->format('%H');
    #Retornamos las horas, los minutos y los segundos
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $h, $i->format('%i'), $i->format('%s'));
}
```

### Ejemplo de uso

```
$minutos = 63000800;
var_dump(minutesToTime($minutos));
```

**Salida:**

```
string(13) "1050013:20:00"
```

En `63000800` tienes entonces: `1050013` horas, `20` minutos y `00` segundos.

Answer (score 0):

Realicé algunas mejoras al código anterior, sin embargo estoy casi seguro que se puede hacer de otra manera más óptima y sencilla. Quedo atento a quién desee dejarme algo mucho mejor...

```
 if ($minutosCursos != 0) {
  $segundosCurso = $minutosCursos * 60;
  $horas = floor($segundosCurso / 3600);
  $horas = ($horas < 10 ? 0 . $horas : $horas);
  $minutos = floor(($segundosCurso - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
  $minutos = ($minutos < 10 ? 0 . $minutos : $minutos);
  $segundos = $segundosCurso - ($horas * 3600) - ($minutos * 60);
  $segundos = ($segundos < 10 ? 0 . $segundos : $segundos);
  $tiempoTotalUsuarioCursos = $horas . ':' . $minutos . ':'  . $segundos;
} else {
  $tiempoTotalUsuarioCursos = '00:00:00';
}
```